# Unable to transfer files from Mi A1 to PC and wifi is also not working

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, usb, mi-a1, mi

I have a Mi A1 device which I didn't use for months and today I charged it to root for some work. I am sure Wifi was working earlier, but not sure about USB file transfer. (I didn't check wifi this time, just charged and started the rooting process)

I was able to unlock the bootloader and root the device and while I was in TWRP, I was able to transfer files from my PC to the android device. After rooting this device, I am seeing this

1. When I tried turning the wifi on, it automatically disables the wifi. I click the enable button and it automatically disables.
2. I wanted to connect the device using ADB, but when I connect the USB cable to the PC, its not showing up in ADB. Its not even showing in windows explorer where you can transfer files.

I am not sure how to solve this issue.

**Mi A1 device running Android 9**

Comment: if formatting userdata did not solve your problem, you probably messed up some wifi related partition. go back to square one and start from working firmware